# Width of elements on activity aren't right?

Tags: android, eclipse, dpi

I have the layout of my app set to 480dpi wide, and 480/4 is 120. So, if I have 4 buttons at the top of my app, and I set one to 120dpi wide, why does the button take up half the screen?! How can I get buttons to get sized evenly at the top?

Here, I just added 4 buttons at the top:

[image]

Then the first two buttons are 120 dpi wide:

[image]

Comment: Post your layout xml file code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hmm. That didn't do anything. I still can't see the buttons

Comment: Ok it worked. I had to add that LinearLayout inside my other LinearLayout. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use FILL_PARENT parameter for layout width and add a weight 1 to each of your buttons to get desired effect

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. So the width of each button is "FILL_PARENT" and the LinearLayout of the Activity is still "match_parent"? And what do you mean "add a weight 1" to the buttons? When I do that, it says I need to supply a layout_width attribute and I can't see the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="100" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</TableRow>
```